# Heapsort swap and comparisons. How to pass them through two functions

Tags: c++, sorting, heapsort

I'm trying to count swaps and comparisons of Heap Sort algorithm in c++. So far I have written main function and also two methods(both for heap sort algorithm).

```
int main()
{
    int countComp = 0, countSwap = 0;
    int arr[] = {12, 11, 13, 5, 6, 7};
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);

    heapSort(arr, n, countComp, countSwap);

    cout << "Sorted array is \n";
    printArray(arr, n);

    cout << "comparisons: " << countComp <<  " swaps: " << countSwap << endl;
}
```

I know I'm making somekind of logical mistake because it is very confusing to me to pass variables through parameters and then call those functions with recursion.

```
void heapify(int arr[], int n, int i, int& countComparisons, int& countSwaps)
{
    int largest = i;  // Initialize largest as root
    int l = 2*i + 1;  // left = 2*i + 1
    int r = 2*i + 2;  // right = 2*i + 2

    // If left child is larger than root
    if (l < n && arr[l] > arr[largest])
    {
        countComparisons++;
        largest = l;
    }

    // If right child is larger than largest so far
    if (r < n && arr[r] > arr[largest])
    {
        countComparisons++;
        largest = r;
    }

    // If largest is not root
    if (largest != i)
    {
        countSwaps++;
        swap(arr[i], arr[largest]);

        // Recursively heapify the affected sub-tree
        heapify(arr, n, largest, countComparisons, countSwaps);
    }
}

// main function to do heap sort
void heapSort(int arr[], int n, int& countComparisons, int& countSwaps)
{
    // Build heap (rearrange array)
    for (int i = n / 2 - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        heapify(arr, n, i, countComparisons, countSwaps);

    // One by one extract an element from heap
    for (int i=n-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        countSwaps++;
        // Move current root to end
        swap(arr[0], arr[i]);

        // call max heapify on the reduced heap
        heapify(arr, n, 0, countComparisons, countSwaps);
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure mistake is related with parameter which is being passed by reference. Could someone correct me please. I'm stuck with this problem. Or maybe there is a better way to count swaps and comparisons?

If I run this, I get answer :
**comparisons: 12 swaps: 16**

Comment: It's not clear to me what part of this solution isn't working. What exactly are you asking? Are you simply unsure of your solution and looking for validation?

Comment: I'm assuming it is working not properly. I would like to know what answer should I get. Because it seems not logical to have more swaps than comparisons with 5 elements in array.

Comment: You need to have comparison *before* if, not inside.

Comment: `countComparisons++;` should not be dependent on the comparison. You are only counting if the comparison is true.

Comment: so for countComparisons++; to be not dependent on the comparison, I should put countComparisons++ before if statement? but what about swaps? I have put it before, now I get comparisons: 38 swaps: 16. is it right?

Comment: Put `countComparisons++;` before the if.

Comment: ***now I get comparisons: 38 swaps: 16. is it right?*** You could use your debugger and check yourself. I would try with a smaller input array.

Comment: And am I doing swap count correctly?

Comment: ***And am I doing swap count correctly?*** I am not 100% sure. I have not debugged your code.

Comment: I have two ifs that looks if children are greater than root. If I will put countComparisons++ before if it will increment it twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> Sorted array is
> 13, 12, 11, 5, 7, 6,
> comparisons: 12 swaps: 16
> ```

You have an error in `heapSort` which lead to the wrong sort result. It also causes increased number of comparisons and swaps in a failed attempt to sort successfully. Change `n` to `i` in the second call to `heapify`

```
void heapSort(int arr[], int n, int& countComparisons, int& countSwaps)
{
    for(int i = n / 2 - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        heapify(arr, n, i, countComparisons, countSwaps);

    for(int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        countSwaps++;
        swap(arr[0], arr[i]);
        //heapify(arr, n, 0, countComparisons, countSwaps);
        heapify(arr, i, 0, countComparisons, countSwaps); //<=== changed `n` to `i`
    }
}
```

Result:

> ```
> Sorted array is
> 5, 6, 7, 11, 12, 13,
> comparisons: 7 swaps: 11
> ```

[Test on ideone](https://ideone.com/xYeS8I)